# Telerik winforms ganttview - How to resize panels from code?

Tags: winforms, telerik

Could you please help me in how to resize (move the splitter) the 2 panels shown in radGanttView from c# code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out the Gantt structure related article http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/ganttview-structure.html and you'll find that the left pane is called GanttViewTextViewElement. There is a method called SetBounds(Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32) in the server-side API of the GanttViewTextViewElement that should allow you to resize the left pane. See these articles for more information:
http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/allmembers_t_telerik_wincontrols_ui_ganttviewtextviewelement.html
and
http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/m_telerik_wincontrols_radelement_setbounds_1.html.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be using the **Ratio** property of the control, which would set what part of the whole control width the GanttViewTextViewElement would take:

```
  radGanttView1.Ratio = 0.2f;
```